# how to keep only one parameter in a subject?

Tags: angular, rxjs, reactive-programming, subject-observer

from a controller I input a parameter to a subject

```
  selectImport(event){
      this.importacionService.onChildSelectImportChanged.next(event);
  }
```

and from my component `importacion.component.ts` I subscribe to this subject

```
this.importacionService.onSelectImportChanged.subscribe( addImport => {

    this.importacionService.addImport(this.month, addImport);
   });


  }
```

Now everything is fine but when I close the dialog of importacion.component.ts and I'll do it again, the subject creates a second suscbripcion and therefore 2 observers, then when I enter a new data with .next() the subscriber runs twice .

how can I control this behavior,
my expected behavior is that only exist and parameter in my subject and only run when its value changes

Comment: You just need to unsubscribe when closing the dialog

Comment: I get an error with this message "object unsubscribed"

Answer (score 1):

Put this in your component

```
private subscription: Subscription;

ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription = this.importacionService.onSelectImportChanged.subscribe(...);
}

ngOnDestroy() {
    if (this.subscription){
        this.subscription.unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

You need to unsubscribe from observables you create or manage yourself

Comment: I tried it that way but when I open the dialog again it generates an error

Comment: Look at this: https://toddmotto.com/passing-data-angular-2-components-input try using inputs and outputs to pass data between components

Comment: I get an error with this message "object unsubscribed"

Comment: For anyone else wondering how you get the "object unsubscribed" error: you get it by calling unsubscribe on a subject rather than the subscription returned from `.subscribe`.

Comment: @LuisRuizFigueroa updated code example to unsub from subscription rather than subject.